# Can a wall hung toilet in a basement be tied into existing drain from upper level or does it require dedicated drain?

Tags: plumbing

Can a wall hung toilet in a basement be tied into existing drain from upper level or does it require dedicated drain

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the connection does not require waste to flow upwards, yes typically. However, checking that the waste pipes and septic system if present can handle the additional fixture is still necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Wall hung toilets are put in basements so that it is easier to slope the exit drainage to the main stack.  With some models you might get an extra foot upwards which is huge for a basement you don't want to dig out.  Toilets don't have to be on their own sub branch although it is usually done that way.